# How to retrieve list of AWS AutoScalingGroups in Java filtered by a specified String?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

In AWS console, you can search for all autoscalinggroups and filter by a string if the name contains that string. Is it possible to do the same in Java?

I see that I can do the following through the Java API:

```
AmazonAutoScalingClient scalingClient = new AmazonAutoScalingClient(awsCredentials);
DescribeAutoScalingGroupsResult autoScalingGroups = scalingClient.describeAutoScalingGroups();
```

But, is there a way to say "only return autoscalinggroups if name contains specified string" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is not a direct way, since AWS Java APIs are usually a direct mapping to the REST API of AWS:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeAutoScalingGroups.html

And that API does not offer the feature you mention.

Also, Java API does not let you specify that:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/autoscaling/model/DescribeAutoScalingGroupsRequest.html

Therefore, I'd recommend to get all the autoscaling groups using existing functions and filter the result with regular expressions. That list should not be large.